# Java plugin unavailable on Firefox 45.0

Tags: java, firefox, applet

I'm running windows 10 and my java plugin in Firefox 45.0 was out of date. I downloaded a newer version (windows 64bit) from the following link
https://www.java.com/en/download/manual.jsp

From the java control panel I have 'java content in the browser' enabled. I have restarted Firefox but I'm still getting the following error on pages that require a java plugin: `The applet cannot run because your java plug-in is not available.`

On the Firefox add-ons page, the java plugin is no longer displayed - where has it disappeared to?

Why is it so difficult to install java plugin on Firefox?

Any one know how to configure this. I've scoured the web and hundreds of forums without any joy.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I installed the wrong version. I have the 32 bit Firefox version, so should have installed the 32 bit Java version.